# Merge these wget & egrep commands for recursive download of sitemap

Tags: grep, cygwin, wget

I am trying to find a way to make these work together. Whereas I can run this successfully using Wget for Windows:

```
wget --html-extension -r http://www.sitename.com
```

this downloads every single file on my server that is directory linked from the root domain. I'd rather download only the pages in my sitemap. For this, I found the following trick which uses CygWin:

```
wget --quiet https://www.sitename.com/sitemap.xml --output-document - | egrep -o
"http://www\.sitename\.com[^<]+" | wget --spider -i - --wait 1
```

However this is only checking that the pages exist, not downloading them as static HTML files as the prior wget command is doing.

Is there a way to merge these and download the sitemap pages as local html files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the man page for `wget`, you will see that the `--spider` entry is as follows:

```
--spider
       When invoked with this option, Wget will behave as a Web spider, which means that it will not download the pages, just check that they are there.
```

All you need to do to actually download the file is remove the `--spider` from your command.

```
wget --quiet https://www.sitename.com/sitemap.xml --output-document - | egrep -o \
"https?://www\.sitename\.com[^<]+" | wget -i - --wait 1
```

Comment: I tried literally everything but that, thanks! Will be testing this method today. Is there a reason you added the "?" in the egrep https pattern?

Comment: @Whitesky when I was testing the command, I ran into some issues where sites would not keep a consistent `http://` or `https://` scheme, so I added an `s?`, which means the `s` is optional.